# Hibernate queries where with many-to-many fields

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, detachedcriteria

I have a model A that has a many to many with B, which has a property c. Like the following.

```
class A {
  @ManyToMany
  List<B> bs;
}

class B {
  @ManyToMany
  List<A> as;
  String c;
}
```

Is there a way (using detached criteria) to do a query like this: select all As where there exists a b in bs where b.c = some value? And if I can how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I research some more and I found a way to do it. For those interested:

```
DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class)
  .addAlias("bs", "b")
  .add(Restrictions.eq("b.c", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

`from A a inner join a.bs b where b.c = ?`

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work okay like that. But is there any way to do it with DetachedCriterias?